# Why is StreamWriter altering the text it writes to a file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a class library, written in C#, that I use to write error and other information out to text or log files.  The problem is that it is altering the text when it writes it to the file.  It is being called by a vb.net application.

**The text that should be written:** `02-20-2017 08:17:42 - Personality Update() beginning:`

**The text that is actually being written:** `02-20-2017 08:17:42 - Per42onaliA17 Up20aAe() beA.D.inninA.D.:`

Below is the code that calls the method to write out the string.

```
errHandler.AddLineToLogFile(Me.MasterLogFileName, "Personality Update() beginning:")
```

Below is the method that gets called.

```
    public void AddLineToLogFile(string logFile, string message, bool replaceExistingFile = false)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFile, !replaceExistingFile))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss - " + message));
            writer.WriteLine(" ");
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: why are you doing message.ToString() on a string variable?

Comment: "message" is already string you dont need to convert to string.

Comment: Your message is also in the ToString() from the 'now' DateTime. so that's why character 's' is being transformed to 42 (s stands for seconds), etc...

Comment: A better question is why are you writing your own logging code?  Just use one of the existing frameworks like log4net or NLog or Logger.Net.

Answer (score 9):

You pass the message as part of the date format. Parts that match a known format are replaced with values from `now`. Add the message **after** formatting your `DateTime`:

```
now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " - " + message
```

- `s` = The second (`42`)
- `t` = The first character of the AM/PM designator (`A`)
- `y` = The year, from 0 to 99 (`17`)
- `d` = The day (`20`)
- `g` = The period or era (`A.D.`)

That's why

> **MM**-**dd**-**yyyy** **HH**:**mm**:**ss** - Per**s**onali**ty** Up**d**a**t**e() be**g**innin**g**:

becomes

> 02-20-2017 08:17:42 - Per42onaliA17 Up20aAe() beA.D.inninA.D.:

A full list of custom date formats can be found [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is the most precise and complete answer, also explaining the issue not just posting the code fix..

Comment: Thank you.  That makes perfect sense.  I should have figured it out myself.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

you are converting `now`to string and your other text is inside that `ToString` method.
Seperate those two and it should be ok.

```
 writer.WriteLine(now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " - " + message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFile, !replaceExistingFile))
{
    writer.WriteLine(now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")  + "- " + message);
    writer.WriteLine(" ");
}
```